# Не могу понять предназначение строчки в while-цикле

Tags: java

```
public class Power {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int e;
        int result;

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            result = 1;
            e = i;
            while(e > 0) {
                result *= 2;
                e = e--;// Не могу понять за чем?
            }
            System.out.println("2 в степени " + i + " равно:" + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `e = e--` отнимает `1` от `е` чтоб из цикла выйти

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> e = e-- отнимает 1 от е чтоб из цикла выйти (@МаксимСтепанов)

Проблема в том, что здесь постфиксный декремент (`--`), а это значит, что переменной `e` сначала присваивается `e` , а `--` буд-то не добирается до `e`, образуется бесконечный цикл. Кроме 1 из внешнего цикла `for`  в условие цикла `while` ничего не дойдет.

*На выходе*

```
2 в степени 0 равно:1
```

и беконечный цикл `while`

Выход из ситуации - применить декремент в префиксной форме, и тогда в `--e` сначала вычтится единица, потом результат присвоится `e`. Условие цикла получив ноль не сработает и он завершится.

*[На выходе](https://ideone.com/Cmv7cm)* (здесь же можно попереставлять декремент)

```
2 в степени 0 равно:1
2 в степени 1 равно:2
2 в степени 2 равно:4
2 в степени 3 равно:8
2 в степени 4 равно:16
2 в степени 5 равно:32
2 в степени 6 равно:64
2 в степени 7 равно:128
2 в степени 8 равно:256
```

Comment: Только сегодня зарегистрировался. И сразу столько положительных эмоций. Всем добра. Всем большое спасибо.

Comment: @TimurVI да, спасибо, и правда, не обратил внимания... а можете подсказать, если не трудно. Сейчас запустил тот же код в студии, с++. Там почему-то выполнилось нормально. Как-то по другому постфиксный декремент работает что ли?

Comment: @SlipQuack если ответ Вам помог, пометьте его как "верный", если не трудно.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов: признаться вам в c++ этой особенности не знаю. Наверняка кто-нибудь да подскажет. [вроде так же устроено](http://cppstudio.com/post/282/)

Comment: @TimurVI а вообще все равно не понимаю. Вот сначала `e=e`. Но ведь потом, в этой же итерации, все равно выполняется `e--`? В итоге `е` все-таки должно декрементироваться до следующей итерации.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов: сначала присваивание, потом декремент, только "поезд уже ушел", переменная `e` уже определилась. Она взяла то, что ей дали и все, в силу специфики постфиксного декремента.

Comment: @TimurVI да разобрался, туплю. Зачем интересно так написали, ведь это явно пример откуда-то. Ведь можно было просто написать `e-- `. Спасибо Вам за ответы и терпение =)

Comment: @SlipQuack, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Пример из Java 8. Руководство для начинающих. 6-е издание Герберд Шилд

Comment: Как пометить Ваши правильные ответы

Comment: просто там, наверное, `e=` лишнее, `e--` было бы достаточно.